# Using the MAC ID of an IP Camera as a unique key

Tags: c#

I have a c# app that plays video stream from a IP Camera.  Can I use the MAC ID of that IP Camera as the unique identifier in the assumption that no other IP Camera with have the same MAC ID?

Incidentally, will the uuid of a web cam be unique as well?

Comment: Why do you need this uniqueness?

Comment: Hi, various reasons. But chiefly i want a universal ID of the IP camera to identify it with my server app.

Comment: Okay, take a look at this answer: [Are MAC addresses unique when coming out of the factory?](http://superuser.com/a/268009)

Comment: Hi, that was the clarification I needed. Thanks

Comment: Using the MAC address is only useful if you can access it. If the server and cameras can potentially be on separate subnets, then you will need some application level API to access the MAC at the server. The IP connection will only provide the MAC of the transit point on the current subnet - camera if local, router otherwise. Using the UUID may be a better proxy that is then accessible to the application.

Comment: hmm, interesting.   many thanks